# How to find limit for Gauss's divergence theorem over a surface

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, divergence-operator

Suppose I have a integral 
$$ I = \iint \vec{F}\cdot\vec{ds}$$
for 
$$ \vec{F} = 2xy\vec{i} +yz\vec{j} + xz \vec{k}$$

in the region where $x = 0 , y=0, z = 0, y = 3, x+2z = 6.$

I know that I can use Gauss's divergence theorem which would make this problem pretty simple 
that is 
$$\iint \vec{F}\cdot\vec{ds} = \iiint \nabla\cdot\vec{F}\,dV$$

which makes my integral

$$ \iiint (2xy + yz + xz)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

but what would be it's limits? I know that will range from $ y =  0 \rightarrow 3$
but what about $x$ and $z$?

Comment: do you mean z+2x=6, or x+2z=6???

Comment: @SakethMalyala sorry for the typo, fixed it.